# Script/terminal command to convert px values to dp in xml

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

So I am a newbie to using the terminal and scripts. I wanted to know how could I go about changing a list of values in dimens.xml from px to dp and multiply by an appropriate scale factor as well. For instance if I have a file

```
<!-- Test File -->
<dimen name="A">10px</dimen>
<dimen name="B">20px</dimen>

<!-- Other dimens -->
<dimen name="C">30px</dimen>

<dimen name="D">40px</dimen>
```

And I wanted to scale all the values by a factor of 2, to get the output:

```
<!-- Test File -->
<dimen name="A">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="B">40dp</dimen>

<!-- Other dimens -->
<dimen name="C">60dp</dimen>

<dimen name="D">80dp</dimen>
```

Whats the best way to do this? Any details and explanation of the solution would be appreciated as well!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462954/sed-increment-number

Comment: You need show us what you have done.

Comment: Editing of XML documents should be done using XML tools. Consider writing an XSLT and using `xmlstarlet` to apply it from a command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for number in `cat /tmp/file.xml | sed 's/>\([0-9]*\)px</>\n\1\n</g' | grep '^[0-9]*$' | sort | uniq`;do let double=$number*2;sed -i 's/'$number'px/'$double'dp/g' /tmp/file.xml;done
```

Explanation: I capture the numbers and add a newline before and after them, then I grep lines just with a number, then I multiply each one then I replace it in the file, while at the same time changing px to dp.

Comment: So I am to understand this, the sed seems to add 'n' before and after a number that is followed by a px (replacing the px) but the grep seems to return and empty list.

Comment: Not n, but a carriage retun (new line). The idea is to isolate numbers in single lines.

Comment: I mean if I break up the commands and use the sed I get:

    <dimen name="A">n20n</dimen>

but on grepping this I get an empty file.

Comment: I don't understand why your version of sed is interpreting \n as n. Anyway, just do: | tr 'n' '\n' |   between the sed and the grep and that will do

Comment: One last question, how do I make it so that it works for both integer and float values? 

I tried changing it to [0-9]*\.[0-9]*\ but then it stops working for integer values.

Comment: Ah, I see... That's because you are forcing a point. Make it optional too: [0-9]*\.*[0-9]*\ Alternatively (more relaxed): [0-9\.]*

Comment: Ah makes sense. Also will this break if you have duplicate dimens? I mean different names but same dimens values? Because won't the last sed screw up?

Comment: I'm sorry user1536435. I don't get you. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I think what I mean is if you have something like:

<dimen name="A">10px</dimen>
<dimen name="B">20px</dimen>

<dimen name="C">10px</dimen>
<dimen name="D">10px</dimen>
Won't the last sed cause multiple calculations on the second and third 10px, causing incorrect values to appear? This is what seems to be happening now.

Comment: You're right. I've modified my answer. Now there is sort and uniq after the grep avoiding calculating twice.